# Counting repeated values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, count

I am creating a game where the player rolls a dice five times. The results are recorded in an array.

```
private final int diceRolls = 5;
private int[] results = new int[diceRolls];

private void game() {
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<diceRolls; i++) {
        results[i] = randomNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
    Arrays.sort(results);
}
```

I am implementing a scoring system so that if a player rolls 3 of the same number, he scores 10 points (ie. 1, 1, 1, 4, 5). If he rolls 3 of one number and 2 of another he scores 15 points. (ie. 1, 1, 1, 2, 2) How would I do this?

Comment: use bst to manage data if you don't care about the dicing order, e.g. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TreeList.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method may do the trick it is the first solution that Exbury pointed out, however the second one is more optimal.

```
private void game() {
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<diceRolls; i++) {
        results[i] = randomNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
    Arrays.sort(results);
}
```

---

```
private int scoreCalc(int [] results)
{
  int score=0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  {
    int repeated=0;
    for(int j = 0; j < results.length; j++)
    {
      if(results[j] == i)
      {
        repeated++;
      }
    }
    score += countPoints(repeated);
  }
}
private int countPoints(int repetitions){
//here goes the scoring system
}
```

Comment: Since I am fairly certain that this is a homework question for CS 101, this is the correct answer. The assignment is most likely looking for basic loops/flow control and wouldn't be looking for an interview question style answer.

Comment: yes thats correct, it is an assignment piece using basic for loops and if statements

Comment: I think that would not work with results = [1,1,3,3,3] because getting twice the same number is interesting only if you have three times another one

Answer (score 0):

- Dice only has 6 numbers one thing you can do is search each number and make decisions.

Direct Search

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
   int count=0;
   for(int j=0;j<dicecount;j++){
       //check each array element with i+1

   }
}
```

- Maintain a Java Map datastructure to map each number with count value

Map Implementation

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code verify if the number is the same than the precedent. It is following your code after you sorted the array results.

```
int count1 = 1;
int count2 = 1;
boolean sameThanBefore= false;

for (int = 1; i < diceRolls; i++) {
    if (results[i] == results[i-1]) {
        if (sameThanBefore && count1 < 2) {
            count1++;
            sameThanBefore = true;
        } else if (sameThanBefore) {
            count2++;
            sameThanBefore = true;
        }
    } else
        sameThanBefore = false;
}

if ((count1 == 3 && count2 == 2) || (count1 == 2 && count2 == 3))
    score = 15;
else if (count1 == 3 || count2 == 3)
    score = 10;
```